# Apply a function to pandas dataframe and get different sized ndarray output

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scipy

My goal is to get the indexes of the local max heights of a dataframe. These change between 3 and 5 per column.

I have tried using the apply function, but get either the error `Shape of passed values is (736, 4), indices imply (736, 480)` or `could not broadcast input array from shape (0) into shape (1)`.

My matrix is `480x736`.

Here is what I've written for the apply function:

```
import numpy as np
import peakutils
df.apply(lambda x: peakutils.indexes(x, thres=0.02/max(x), min_dist=100))
```

Here is what I am able to get to work:

```
indexes =[]
import numpy as np
import peakutils
for column in df:
    indexes.append(peakutils.indexes(df[column], thres=0.02/max(df[column]), min_dist=100))
```

Often the indexes are 4 in length, but occasionally I'll get 1 more or less:

```
Out[32]: 
[array([ 12, 114, 217, 328, 433]),
 array([ 12, 116, 217, 325, 433]),
 array([ 64, 166, 283, 389]),
 array([105, 217, 326, 433]),
 array([105, 237, 390])]
```

My guess is that the problem with the output comes from my not knowing the shape of the resultant dataframe. The shape is indeterminable from the outset.

**How do I apply a function to a df where the output differs in size & type?**

Comment: I am able to get it to work with scipy, `df.apply(lambda x: find_peaks_cwt(x, np.arange(1, 200)))`, but this is much slower, and no where near as clean.

Comment: wrap your `lambda` return value in a `pd.Series`  `df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(peakutils.indexes(x, thres=0.02/max(x), min_dist=100)))`

Comment: I can accept the answer if you want to post it as one. I don't understand why it failed, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pandas is trying to do "something" with the arrays.  You can short circuit that "something" by wrapping your `lambda`'s return value in a `pd.Series`

Try this:

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(peakutils.indexes(x, thres=0.02/max(x), min_dist=100)))
```